# Check if string contains one value or another, syntax error?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm coming from a javascript backend to Python and I'm running into a basic but confusing problem

I have a string that can contain a value of either 'left', 'center', or 'right'. I'm trying to test if the variable contains either 'left' or 'right'.

In js its easy:

```
if( str === 'left' || str === 'right' ){}
```

However, in python I get a syntax error with this:

```
if str == 'left' || str == 'right':
```

Why doesn't this work, and what's the right syntax?

Comment: A note: You should never shadow built-in names (like `str`, `int`, `iter` or - very popular - `list`).

Comment: For the benefit of anyone confused by the ambiguous "contains": @Geuis wants `str === 'left'` etc. The js (Javascript) `===` means "exactly equal to" without type coercion. See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python's [logical OR operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) is called `or`.  There is no `||`.

```
if string == 'left' or string == 'right':
##                  ^^
```

BTW, in Python this kind of test is usually written as:

```
if string in ('left', 'right'):

## in Python ≥3.1, also possible with set literal
## if string in {'left', 'right'}:
```

Also note that [`str` is a built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str) in Python. You should avoid naming a variable that clashes with them.

Comment: What is the difference between || and or in Python?

Comment: Yes, logical or is `or`. The bitwise or is still `|` (unlike e.g. in Pascal (dialects?), which is rather weird). Edit @ Geius: There is no `||` in Python. That's why you get a syntax error and not unexpected behaviour.

Comment: | is a bitwise "or" operator in Python.  However, it doesn't make sense when two of them are together, as in "||".  Hence, the syntax error.